# Blank HTML SELECT without blank item in dropdown list in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

**Problem:** I have form that works fine. However, I am not able to set a blank item to appear in the dropdown list.

I am new to both angular and javascript and I have not been able to figure it out.

I have the following line of code:

```
$scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
```

and here is the form:

```html
 <div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-body">
  <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form" ">
   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
            <option value=""></option>
        <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
        <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select></div>

   <hr />
   <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important"><strong>* OR Search by Zip code radius *</strong></div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles" required>
        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option><!---<option >5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option>--->
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
    <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
   </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField()" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search"/></div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

How would I set a blank item to appear but have the value: 5 be the default value when I run the form. So when the user enters the page, the miles is set blank but will still generate a result when the user enters a name of a hospital and city. If users enters zip code, it will generate an alert.

**Update** I have tried the following as suggested by Sibi Raj to do the following:

```
<select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" required>
                        <option selected disabled value=''></option>
                        <option ng-repeat="data in miles" value={{data.value}}>{{data.value}}</option>
                    </select>
```

Works fine however it creates an extra line:

[image]

and when I inspect, I get this weird value populating:

[image]

How would I remove that unknown blank space?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Sibi Saj, I was able to create a blank space to appear in the textbox and still have results appear when the user enters a hosptial name and city location.

However, when I enter a zip code and select a range, meaning miles, rather then showing a hospital within the mileage, it will show the whole results.

The following is the script that Sibi Saj helped me with:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    // Controller
    myApp.controller('demoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.searchParam = {
        distance: 5 //set the value to the select box
      }
      $scope.miles = [{
        'value': '5'
      }, {
        'value': '10'
      }, {
        'value': '15'
      }, {
        'value': '20'
      }];
    }]) 

    // directive that converts number-string to number 
    myApp.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
            return val != null ? parseInt(val, 10) : null;
          });
          ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
            return val != null ? '' + val : null;
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

How would I get results to appear that are within the miles based on the zip code?

Comment: In your code, there is two option field in addition to the ng-repeat option, remove any one from the top. @Robert Flores

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: I have removed that option ans yet it is still appearing. I am not sure what it can be

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put an option inside the repeat:

```
<select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles" required>
    <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''>
      <option value="5"></option>
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @ Pritam: I would I add that to the $scope.miles? I am not sure how to do that based on what basic understanding i have

Comment: @RobertoFlores Can you try the above?

Comment: @ Pritam: It doesnt work. ng-options-"..." has set values and when I set the value to blank, it doesnt work. I can not remove because it will break other parts of the form

Comment: @ Pritam: I have tried that but when the form is first rendered in the page, it does not show the the "Selected" in the dropdown menu list. I would like it to display but have the default "5" still active. So I would like to appear when the page starts

Answer (score 0):

instead of ng options, you could use ng-repeat

```
<select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" required>
    <option selected disabled value=''>Select</option>
      <option ng-repeat="data in miles" value={{data.value}}>{{data.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @ SibiRaj: I have tried your approach. Yes it does show in the drop down but I would like it to appear blank at the beginning. Meaning, when the page first renders, instead of showing the default 5, I would like it to show blank. So when a user enters a hospital and city, it will show the results even the mile drop down is blank.

Comment: This looks like it would have a blank option, with the word 'Select'.  You could just remove the label and it would actually look blank.  Is that what you're trying to acheive?

Comment: yes,@RobertoFlores I think you are looking for what @Nicholas Smith said

Comment: @NicholasSmith and @ Sibi Raj: Yes you are both correct, however, as you can see in my updated question, I have done that however an extra space is occurring and I am not sure how to remove the extra space

Comment: I got it, it is because the select the $scope.miles have numbers as values and the select has a string. check out my new answer @RobertoFlores

Answer (score 0):

Add the convert to number directive to your code "convert-to-number" in the select element

In HTML

```
  <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance" required convert-to-number>
<option value="">Select Me</option>
<option value={{v.value}} ng-repeat="(k , v) in miles track by $index">{{v.value}}</option>
```

Script(don't forget to add the directive)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Controller
myApp.controller('demoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
  $scope.searchParam = {
    distance: 5 //set the value to the select box
  }
  $scope.miles = [{
    'value': '5'
  }, {
    'value': '10'
  }, {
    'value': '15'
  }, {
    'value': '20'
  }];
}]) 

// directive that converts number-string to number 
myApp.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return val != null ? parseInt(val, 10) : null;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return val != null ? '' + val : null;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/srCJAgJ9fnOnbVzp5FL3?p=preview

Comment: post a reply if it works, it should work @Roberto Flores

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: It does work however, when the page is first generated, it displays 5 in the text field in the drop down box for miles. I have been trying to have a blank space but still have the 5 miles default as the value so when the user enters the name of the hospital and location, it will display the result becuase it has the default distance of 5

Comment: @RobertoFlores, check now, https://plnkr.co/edit/srCJAgJ9fnOnbVzp5FL3?p=preview ( I hope this is what you expect)

Comment: it is now blank, just displays select Me as a text, by the value is empty, If you want you can remove that.

Comment: if you want it so blank then just remove select me text from the option field.

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: What do you mean by dont forget to add the directive?

Comment: If You going to show any default value at first, add that directive, but you are not showing any, so no need to add that directive @RobertoFlores

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: I have reviewed the answer. However, it does not render any results when I add the code. Nothing happens. I am currently trying to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: @ Sibi Raj : I did not. That is why I said I am trying to resolve or see what you did. It will display the whole results rather then showing results based on the miles when user selects zip code option

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: This is what I did for miles but it isnt working when I implement you code: $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
   try{
    var lon, lat;
    if("geolocation" in navigator){
     window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
      lat = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
      lon = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
      $http.get("/includes/ReturnCurrentZipcode.cfm?Lat=" + lat + "&Lon=" + lon)
      .success(function(response){
       $scope.searchParam.Zip = response;
      })
     })
    }
    else{  }
   }
   catch(err) {  }
  }

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: I am not sure why it is showing all of the results rather then showing results based within the miles

Comment: could you create a plunker, so that I could review your code @RobertoFlores

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: Was that helpful?

Comment: @ Sibi Raj: I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong when I implement you code